# Why can't we see who favorites our question?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I think I know why we cannot see who upvotes or downvotes our question. It might lead to unfavorable confrontations were people ask other people why they voted the way they did. It might also ward people away from voting, due to the lack of anonymity. But I don't see why we cannot see who favorites our questions? Now, I don't doubt there's a good reason, I just want to know.

Surely seeing who favorites a question or yours doesn't lead to bad confrontations. Or am i wrong?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/how-do-you-find-out-who-favorited-a-question

Comment: Thanks, your link does provide a way to find out who favorited my question, albeit in a difficult way. But do you know anything about why it is this way? @MetaEd

Comment: @A.Kvåle You'll have to ask Stack Exchange staff, whose last word on that question stands at "There is no way to retrieve the same information on the site itself and that's currently by design."

Comment: Why would you want to know? What would you do with that info?

Comment: Presuming an actual deliberate design choice, Twitter has a view to see who favorited what, because it is intentionally a social media interface for knowing what people think. But for SE, it is a Q&A to establish knowledge, so authorship is public, but 'liking' (which is voting) comes under the current cultural norm of privacy. Favoriting (or really bookmarking) is even less public, it is only intended to aid an individual user's memory.

Comment: Good. The less we look like Twitter, the better.

Answer (score 6):

When we had "bookmarks" (née "favorites"), it *was* possible to view a person's bookmarks via search, their profile, and most robustly the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/299308/favorite-users-by-question). For the minute details see the [revision history](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11514/3) of this post.

Now that we have "[Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/323179)", they are completely private. In fact, other than the badges that are awarded when enough people save a post, there's no way to tell how many people saved the post.

This was done due to the prevailing opinion that it was weird, unnecessary, and unexpected that it would be public.

It's also possible to "follow" a post, which allows you to get notifications for it. This is also private (and always has been).

Comment: I for one just bookmark the question/answer/thing on my chrome browser.

Comment: Laurel, on Twitter (no idea about Facebook), favorites made by a person are viewable everywhere, in addition to viewing all the people favoriting a given tweet. That is _way_ more public than what I would assume is much more innocuous favoriting here in SE. I'm not judging any choice here (I get where you're coming from), but I don't think you need to be _that_ paranoid about SE.

Comment: Wait...what kinds of things are you favoriting here? Just that you're paranoid is already enough to make you suspect. Stormtroopers deployed. Please stay away from windows.

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't resist.

Comment: No, really. I can't resist. Literally. They won't unlock the door. Pills through a slot. _uncontrollable sobbing_

Comment: I'll have to remember to come back and delete all this.

Comment: Even deleted comments are maintained in the database with just a 'deleted' flag.

Comment: ... just sayin'

Comment: Don't worry, apple/Microsoft/Google/Gmail/Facebook/Instagram/twitter/cookies know everything that there is to know about you.

Comment: You forgot to delete the comments @Mitch

Comment: @A.Kvåle Thanks for the reminder. I'm on it.

Comment: @A.Kvåle I may be a bit slow though.

Comment: @Mitch Waiting-until-a-black-hole-deletes-every-piece-of-information-related-to-the existence-of-the-comments-slow?